# background image with cover overlay.

Tags: html, css, background-image, cover

Im working on a background image that is placed with inline styling, that has a red tint overlaying the image.

The problem occurs when the red tint is covering the content.

How would I make the red tint go under the buttons and text?

Please see [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzp318kb/)

Appreciate the help

```
#cover-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
#cover-wrap .black-cover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#backgrond-cover {
  background-color: #37383a;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
#backgrond-cover .username {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#backgrond-cover .location {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#backgrond-cover .summary {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: (P.S.) You're not properly closing your `username` paragraph. By using a good editor such typo/issues would never happen.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the buttons to be over the overlay red tint. then move the buttons above the plane of the red tint.

to achieve that you need to give a z-index to the button ( imagine z axis in graph) positive value brings it above and negative values push it down. But to give a relative positioning of z axis you also have to specify the css position to relative

add this css to the bottom of your code...

```
   button{
       position:relative;
       z-index:10;
   }
```

now this will target all buttons in the page. If you want to target only specific buttons, give the buttons an id or class.

Also there is a unclosed paragraph tag in your code < / p >. Not sure if you had a copy paste error  or not

Comment: moving the tint wont help you, because you want your image then on top of that you want tint and on top of that tint you want your buttons ( if i understood it correctly). Now imagine what you want with relation to a graph. what values would you give as z axis values to each element?

Comment: I don't mind, I just need the content to be above the red tint.

Comment: so you want the red tint to be over the image but not the content like the text and buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Try this onces..i had brought some changes which does what you want.

```
<div id="cover-wrap">
 <div class="black-cover"></div>  
    <div id="background-cover" class="center">
          <div id='box'>  
          <img src="img/people/heyfitty-girl-9.png" class="main-profile-pic img-circle"/>
              <p class='username'>Cloud #3</p>
              <p class="location">Birmingham</p>
              <p class="summary">Hi, im Paul, Designer / Developer rocking out in Bham</p>

            <button class="cheeky-kiss-btn">Cheeky Kiss</button><span class="or">or</span>

            <button class="hangout-btn">Hang out</button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <!-- html ends here -->

  <!-- css looks like this -->


 #cover-wrap
    {
      position: absolute;
      width: 1350px;
    }
 .black-cover 
    {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
 #backgrond-cover 
    {
      background-color: #37383a;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
       padding: 50px;
       color: #fff;
       background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/20100726_Kalamitsi_Beach_Ionian_Sea_Lefkada_island_Greece.jpg');
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      width:92.6%;
    } 

 #box  
    {
       position: relative;
    }
 #backgrond-cover .username 
    {
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-top: 20px;
    }
 #backgrond-cover .location 
    {
       font-size: 14px;
    }
 #backgrond-cover .summary {
       font-size: 14px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
   /*css ends here */
```

Comment: Thanks for this but the backend image needs to be inline style

Comment: I have edited my last post by adding this display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
width:92.6%; just give a try it if it works or not @PaulDesigner .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry did not read the question. I've updated with the it now working. You need to se the z-index on all elements you want above the red grad or like I did wrap all of them in a div and position that above the grad. Note, need position on all elements you want to use z-index on.

http://jsfiddle.net/MatrixMe/8pmdzms8/1/

HTML

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/20100726_Kalamitsi_Beach_Ionian_Sea_Lefkada_island_Greece.jpg')">

```
      <div class="content-wrapper">
          <img src="img/people/heyfitty-girl-9.png" class="main-profile-pic img-circle"/>
        <p class="username">Cloud #3<p>
        <p class="location">Birmingham</p>
        <p class="summary">Hi, im Paul, Designer / Developer rocking out in Bham</p>
        <button class="cheeky-kiss-btn">Cheeky Kiss</button><span class="or">or</span>
        <button class="hangout-btn">Hang out</button>   
     </div>        
      <div class="black-cover"></div>
```

CSS

```
/*Cover Info*/
#cover-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
div.black-cover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#backgrond-cover {
  background-color: #37383a;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
   z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; 
}
#backgrond-cover .username {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#backgrond-cover .location {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#backgrond-cover .summary {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: having z index as -1 pushes the tint below the whole plane...that is why the tint goes missing..

Comment: Paul 100% right - sorry I did not read the question properly. I've update with changes so that it now does what he needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create overlay by making it absolute but it cover the content, you can play with z-index then. First set z-index of the container to 1, then add z-index -1 to the overlay. This should make overlay placed under the content.

```css
.item{
  background: url(https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/13307/screenshots/1824627/logotypes_1x.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
h1{color: white}
.item:after{
  content:"";
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h1> content here</h1>
</div>
```

The snippet above is make use of after pseudo element to make the overlay rather dan using another HTML tag.

i have restructured your code, deleting unnesessary tag, you can check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/rzp318kb/6/

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```
#backgrond-cover p, #backgrond-cover span, #backgrond-cover button, #backgrond-cover img {
  position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

and add `z-index: 10;` to `#cover-wrap .black-cover`. Should do the trick.